# Pandas dataframe to multi-level nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have data for a course in a dataframe. The flat data looks like this:

```
level,level_description,lesson,lesson_description,problem,hint,status
1,level1,1,lesson 1,1,hint1,Old
1,level1,1,lesson 1,2,hint2,Old
1,level1,1,lesson 1,3,hint3,Old
1,level1,2,lesson 2,4,hint4,Old
1,level1,2,lesson 2,5,hint5,New
2,level2,3,lesson 3,6,hint6,New
2,level2,3,lesson 3,7,hint7,New
```

The data has a relationship level -> lesson -> problems. I.e., a given level has multiple lessons that have multiple problems.

I am trying to convert this flat dataframe to a nested array of objects JSON structure. I would like it to look like this:

```
{"levels": [
    {"1":
        "level_description": level1
        "lessons": [
                {"1":
                    "lesson_description": lesson1
                    "problems": [
                        {"1":
                            "hint": hint1
                            "status": old}
                        {"2":
                            "hint": hint2
                            "status": old}
                        {"3":
                            "hint": hint3
                            "status": old }]}
                {"2":
                    "lesson_description": lesson 2
                    "problems": [
                        {"1":
                            "hint": hint1
                            "status": old}
                        {"2":
                            "hint": hint2
                            "status": old}
                        {"3":
                            "hint": hint3
                            "status": old }]}]
    }
    {"2":
        "level_description": level2
        "lessons": [
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I have tried grouping by subgroups and turning them into dicts:

```py
j = df.groupby(['level', 'level_description', 'lesson', 'lesson_description'])
    .apply(lambda x: x[['problem', 'hint', 'status']].to_dict('records'))
    .reset_index(name='problems'))
h = j.groupby(['level', 'level_description'])
    .apply(lambda x: x[['lesson', 'lesson_description']].to_dict('records'))
    .reset_index(name='lessons'))
result = h.to_dict(orient='records')
```

This gets me close, but I can't get the column names as the keys for the nested dicts. Instead I just get an array of objects, and the column I want to be a key as another value. What I end up with looks like this:

```
{[
        "level": 1
        "level_description": level1
        "lessons": [{
                    "lesson": 1
                    "lesson_description": lesson1
                    "problems": [
                        {   "problem": 1:
                            "hint": hint1
                            "status": old}
                        {
                            "problem": 2
                            "hint": hint2
                            "status": old}
```

What is the best way to get this nested structure from a dataframe? Thanks.

Comment: I made an update to display the data as csv. The "1", "2" are not counts -- they are unique identifiers for the column. Trying this gives me the error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'